# SQL Query group by highest revision number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write an SQL Server query to extract rows with the highest 'Revision' number for each distinct ColumnId.

For example if I have a data set such as:

```
Id  ColumnId  Revision
------------------------
1       1         1
2       1         2
3       1         3
4       2         1
5       2         2
6       2         3
7       2         4
```

My desired result is as follows:

```
Id  ColumnId  Revision
------------------------
3       1        3
7       2        4
```

I tried to use the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT Id, ColumnId, MAX(Revision) As Revision from Bug 
GROUP BY ColumnId
```

If I remove the Id from the query above it partially returns what I need. However I also need the Id column.

What am I missing here to get this query to work as expected?

**EDIT:** 
One thing I haven't made clear from the data set above is that highest Revision number for a particular ColumnId does not necessarily have the highest Id.

```
Id  ColumnId  Revision
------------------------
1       1         1
2       1         3 <- Note this has a higher revision number than row Id 3.
3       1         2 <- This has a lower revision number than row Id 2.
4       2         1
5       2         2
6       2         3
7       2         4
```

Comment: Check my answer... Instead of `id` use `MAX(Id)`

Comment: Interesting, however using MAX(Id) assumes that the row with the highest 'Revision' number also has the highest Id. If I change for example my original data so that Id=2 is Revision 3, and Id=3 is Revision 2, then I will get an incorrect result. Unfortunately I can't make that assumption. Sorry I should have made this clear in my original question.

Comment: Yes, Of course. I thought the same, but based on your example only, I did.

Comment: Another one question, will you insert the Revision value not in sequence? If it is in sequence manner (and Id also), then my answer is also correct.

Comment: @Jesuraja I only have read only access to the data so I'm not inserting any values. In this case I'd prefer not to make an assumption about the sequence. Otherwise, yes your query does work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a subquery and then inner join back on the ColumnId and the MaxRevision like this:

```
SELECT A.Id, A.ColumnId, A.Revision
from Bug A 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ColumnId,  MAX(Revision) As MaxRevision 
FROM BUG
GROUP BY ColumnId ) B ON
A.ColumnId = B.ColumnId AND
A.Revision = B.MaxRevision
```

Comment: I've accepted this answer because although @shree.pat18 has pretty much the exact same query, yours has a little explanation of what it does - which I think will help others with less experienced with SQL who may stumble upon this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER`, for example with a common-table-expression(CTE):

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT Id, ColumnId, Revision, 
           RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnId ORDER BY Revision DESC)
    FROM Bug 
)
SELECT Id, ColumnId, Revision 
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/63992/1/0)</kbd>

Comment: +1 : Though this does make an unstated assumption about which version of SQL Server is being used ;)

Comment: @MatBailie: you need at least SQL-Server 2005 which i've presumed as OP mentioned SQL-Server, otherwise he'd mention the version(imho).

Answer (score 2):

You can get what you want in several ways.  Here is a way using `not exists` that usually performs pretty well:

```
select id, columnid, revision
from bug b
where not exists (select 1
                  from bug b2
                  where b2.columnid = b.columnid and b2.revision > b.revision
                 );
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT b.Id, b.ColumnId, b.Revision from Bug b 
INNER JOIN
(SELECT ColumnID, MAX(Revision) as 'Revision' from Bug GROUP BY ColumnID) m
ON b.ColumnId = m.ColumnId AND b.Revision = m.Revision
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT    MAX(Id) AS ID, ColumnId, MAX(Revision) AS Revision
FROM      Bug 
GROUP BY  ColumnId
```